# Minimal geodesics in $S^{n+1}$

Tags: geometry, differential-topology

Let $\Omega^d(M)$ the space of minimal geodesics on a smooth manifold $M$. How can I prove that if $M= S^{n+1}$, $\Omega^d(S^{n+1}) \simeq S^n$?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *minimal geodesics*?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Minimal are geodesic that minimize energy, as an arc of maximal circle in $S^n$

Comment: I'm missing something. My definition of geodesic is a non-accelerating curve (in the sense that $\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial t} = 0$). What do you mean by "energy"?

Comment: You would prove it by 1) determining *all* the geodesics and 2) looking at the subcollection you call "minimal" (but have not defined for us) and then 3) noticing the minimal ones are determined by their velocity vector at a point.

Comment: What kind of structure do you consider on $ \Omega^d(M) $ ? It is reasonable to think that with this structure the set $ \Omega^d(M) $ should be a differentiable manifold that should inherit a riemannian metric from $ M $. Then do you want to prove that this space is homeomorphic, diffeomerphic or isometric to $ S^n$ ? (in the case $ M=S^{n+1} $)

Comment: Not everyone here knows Physics, so defining minimal geodesics as geodesics that minimize energy is almost as the same as not defining it. So please, add an edit, *defining* mathematically what  we should consider a "minimal geodesic". If you insist in talking about minimize energy, what is the mathematical precise statement of this?

Comment: I'm sure that ArthurStuart means for 'minimal geodesic' a geodesic that minimizes the distance between any two points along it. 'Energy' is not a 'phisical' object. See do Carmo's book for further details. The real problem in his question is that he doesn't precise what kind of structure has to be considered on the space of such geodesic.

Comment: @user55449 It was the first thing I thought about, but this doesn't make sense, since every short geodesic is length minimizing, so every geodesic minimizes the distance between some couple of points. Also, as you asked in a previous comment, what kind of structure do you put on $\Omega^d(M)$?

Answer (score 1):

Arguing by symmetry, we can classify all geodesics of $M = S^{n+1}$.

**Claim:** Every geodesic of $M=S^{n+1}$ is a constant velocity parametrization of $P\cap M$, where $P\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$ is a $2$-plane passing from the origin.

*Proof:* Notice that $M$ is invariant under the action of $O(n+2)$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$. Let $x\in M$ be any point, $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow M$ a (maximally extended) geodesic with $\gamma(0) = x$. Let
$$P=span\left\{\mathbf{x},\frac{d\gamma}{d t}(0)\right\}$$
where $\mathbf{x}$ denotes the vector going from the origin to $x\in M$. Assume that the trace of $\gamma$ is not contained in $P$. Let $S\in O(n+2)$ be the reflection on $P$. Then $\gamma'=P\circ\gamma$ is again a geodesic with $\frac{d\gamma'}{d t}(0) = \frac{d\gamma}{d t}(0)$ and $\gamma'\neq \gamma$, which is a contradiction to the uniqueness of geodesics with given boundary conditions.

$\square$

I hope this helps. If you would define what a "minimal" geodesic is, then I might be able to help you with the rest of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the letter "d" in your notation $\Omega^d(M)$ is referring to a basepoint $d$ (thought of as the north pole), then the space of closed geodesics (for example with the [compact-open topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology) of maps from the circle to the sphere) starting from $d$ is clearly identifiable with a sphere of one dimension lower, because a directed geodesic is uniquely determined by a point on the equatorial hypersphere.

Comment: Only if you consider two geodesics with the same trace but reversed orientation different, else you only get a projective plane. Furthermore if you don't specify the structure you desire to be preserved by your isomorphism and only ask for a bijection, then every set with the same cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $S^n$.

Comment: That's why I specified a *directed* geodesic.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I noticed it too late to edit my comment.